# Неадекватное поведение display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Подскажите, в чем проблема?
Каким образом контейнер *skills* начинает накладываться на предыдущий контейнер *team*, если выставить второму *display flex*? При любом другом значении *display* все нормально, *skills* располагается дальше по странице снизу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
/* Team */
.team-cards {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
}
.spec-card {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
.spec-card:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.spec-card h4 {
    font-size: 15pt;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.spec-card h5 {
    font-size: 14.5pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.spec-card p {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size: 13pt;
}
.spec-card .img {
    height: 110%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.spec-links img {
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.spec-links img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
/* ____ */
/* У skills кроме шрифта стилей больше нет */
```

```html
<div class="team">
  <h2>Our Team</h2>
    <p id="italic">Aliquam dapibus massa diam, eu porta ipsum mollis vel. Etiam blandit auctor</p>
    <div class="team-cards">
    <div class="first-card spec-card">
      <div class="img"></div>
                <h4>Richard Jones</h4>
                <h5>Android Developer</h5>
                <p>Vivamus porta et nunc vitae lacinia. Nam sed fermentum metus. Maecenas ut tortor mi. Maecenas pellentesque ex in bibendum euismod</p>
                <div class="spec-links">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/facebook.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.cn" target="_blank"><img src="assets/linkedin.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/twitter.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://www.plus.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/google-plus-logo.svg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="second-card spec-card">
                <div class="img"></div>
                <h4>Megan Turner</h4>
                <h5>Print Designer</h5>
                <p>Vivamus porta et nunc vitae lacinia. Nam sed fermentum metus. Maecenas ut tortor mi. Maecenas pellentesque ex in bibendum euismod</p>

                <div class="spec-links">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/facebook.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.cn" target="_blank"><img src="assets/linkedin.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/twitter.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://www.plus.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/google-plus-logo.svg" alt=""></a>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="third-card spec-card">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <h4>Victor Green</h4>
                    <h5>IT Programmer</h5>
                    <p>Vivamus porta et nunc vitae lacinia. Nam sed fermentum metus. Maecenas ut tortor mi. Maecenas pellentesque ex in bibendum euismod</p>
                    <div class="spec-links">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/facebook.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.cn" target="_blank"><img src="assets/linkedin.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/twitter.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://www.plus.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/google-plus-logo.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="fourth-card spec-card">
                    <div class="img"></div>
                    <h4>Amy Watkins</h4>
                    <h5>Digital Marketing Specialist</h5>
                    <p>Vivamus porta et nunc vitae lacinia. Nam sed fermentum metus. Maecenas ut tortor mi. Maecenas pellentesque ex in bibendum euismod</p>
                    <div class="spec-links">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/facebook.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.cn" target="_blank"><img src="assets/linkedin.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/twitter.svg" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="https://www.plus.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="assets/google-plus-logo.svg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills">
            <h2>Our Skills</h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: В показанном примере он и без флекса тоже накладывается...

Comment: А вообще причина всех проблем скорее всего в `height: 110%` так как вы создали бесконечную рекурсию

Comment: @andreymal про какую рекурсию идет речь? объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: @andreymal нет, например при grid или block наложения нет

Comment: Да и высота 110% здесь тоже не решает, хотя избавиться от нее стоит все равно

Comment: @АртёмШлянов значит вы приложили в вопросу сломанный пример, который не воспроизводит реальную проблему

Answer (score 0):

@andreymal прав, всё дело в height: 110%. img которому задано это свойство не является прямым потомком flex-контейнера, поэтому он и выпадает из потока.
Кроме очевидного убрать height: 110%, можно попробовать задать свойство overflow .spec-card.

```
.spec-card {        
    margin-right: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```